# Generic type extending Number, calculations

Tags: java, generics, math

I've made an interface of math operation with one method, calculate, taking various number of arguments

```
public interface MathOperation {
    public <T extends Number> T calculate(T... args);
}
```

There's also simple implementation of this class, which does not work:

```
private class Sum implements MathOperation {
    @Override
    public <T extends Number> T calculate(T... args) {
        return args[0] + args[1];
    }
}
```

The problem is:

```
bad operand types for binary operator '+'
  first type:  T
  second type: T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Number declared in method <T>calculate(T...)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a simple class, taking for example two Doubles and returning Double as well.

Is there possibility to achieve this?

Comment: `+` cannot be applied to types that `extend Number`. `new Integer(5) +  new Integer(5)` works because of autoboxing. You will have to look at the runtime type of `args` and do the operation accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but the problem for someone who has worked with C++ templates before is, that in Java you cannot use the + operator on generic types like the OP has tried.

Answer (score 4):

`+` cannot be applied to types that `extend Number`. `new Integer(5) + new Integer(5)` works because of autoboxing. You will have to look at the runtime type of args and do the operation accordingly.

Something on the lines of:

```
private class Sum implements MathOperation {
    @Override
    public <T extends Number> T calculate(Class<T> clazz, T... args) {
         if (clazz.equals(Integer.class))
         {
             return Integer.class.cast(args[0]) + Integer.class.cast(args[1]);
         } else (....) 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid, if..else statement for every class extending Number. There was deleted post with working solution, the problem is it always returns Double: http://pastebin.com/x7KizHPu

Comment: I wrote a comment on that deleted answer that it does not work. This is because not all `integers` can be represented as a `float`. With the current Java language, there is no way this can be done without reflection. Your best bet is to minimize the casting to a single place, which is possible.

Comment: I know about this problem, but it's minor.

Comment: Can you please explain why it is minor?

Comment: @Visher: There's no way to do what you're trying to do in Java.  You're better off not trying to write generic arithmetic tools at all.

Comment: Cause it's not about doing anything serious with those calculations.

Comment: Are you saying that it is ok to get wrong results? Because that is what will happen. I sort of agree with @LouisWasserman, think about the client code, I suspect it will not provide any real benefits.

Comment: Use `(Integer)` n instead of `Integer.class.cast(n)`. The `Class::cast(Object)` method exists for dynamic conversions, e. g, `anyClazz.cast(anyObject)`.

Answer (score 1):

For Addition we can use `doubleValue()` method of `Number` class. To return the same type value, the idea is to use a `Function` or `Supplier` or a `Factory` to create instances of the type T.

```
class MathOperation<T extends Number> {
  
    public double add(T a, T b) {
        double d = a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
        return d;
    }

    public T add(T a, T b, Function<Double,T> function) {
        double d = a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
        return function.apply(d);
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test the runtime type as shown in the other answers. Or you can try a different design: Create an abstract class that works as a factory:

```
interface MathContext<T extends Number> {

    ...

    T valueOf(double d);
    T valueOf(int i);
    T add (T... args);
}
```

And concrete classes for the types that you want to use:

```
DoubleContext implements MathContext<Double> {

    ...

    Double valueOf(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    Double valueOf(double d) {
        return d;
    }

    Double add(Double... args) {
        Double res = 0;
        for (Double arg: args)  {
            res += arg;
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Now you could implement your MathOperation using that class. However, it's not really needed any more.