# Java Generics - Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'T', 'T'

Tags: java, generics

I've been learning Java, recently learned about generic types and wanted to use them in a linear algebra framework I've been working on. Here is some source code.

```
package vector;

import java.util.Arrays;

abstract class AbstractVector <T> {

    T[] vector;

    public T get(int index) { return this.vector[index]; }

    public void set(int index, T value) { this.vector[index] = value; }

    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(this.vector);
    }

    public double dotProduct(AbstractVector<T> vector) {
        double value = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<vector.size(); i++) {

            // This line causes issues
            value += this.vector[i] * vector.get(i);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.vector.length;
    }

}
```

When I try to use any math operations on my generic types I get an error Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'T', 'T'. How one does fix this issue?

Comment: By not performing math operations on generic types. It could be **any** type. Like a `Dog`. What does it mean to perform multiplication on a `Dog` class? Java **does not** support operator overloading on user types.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch answered it pretty well. To fix the issue you could limit T to extending Numbers so `public class AbstractVector <T extends Number>`

Comment: @LuciferUchiha I am sorry, that is not enough. Java does math on primitive numeric types (including `char`), not on `Number` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Lucifer Uchiha is on the right track in the comment:

> To fix the issue you could limit T to extending Numbers so public
> `class AbstractVector <T extends Number>`

Your first step is to tell Java that your vector can hold only numbers, not any reference type.

```
abstract class AbstractVector <T extends Number> {
```

We’re still not there, though. While Java can automatically unbox `Integer` to `int` and `Double` to `double` when used in an arithmetic expression, it doesn’t know which primitive type to unbox `T` to, not even knowing that `T` is some subclass of `Number`. If you know that you always want the dot product as a `double`, the solution is quite simple since `Number` has a `doubleValue` method declared (it’s implemented in each subclass individually, but we don’t need to care).

```
        // This line no longer causes issues
        value += this.vector[i].doubleValue() * vector.get(i).doubleValue();
```

We’re done.

You may find further inspiration in this related question: [Generic type extending Number, calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946947/generic-type-extending-number-calculations).

Comment: Thanks for the addition I forgot about that part :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform mathematical operations in Java, we can use `NUMBER` class.
The `java.lang.Number` class is the superclass of classes `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger` , `Byte`, `Double`, `Float`, `Integer`, `Long`, and `Short`.The Subclasses of Number must provide methods to convert the represented numeric value to `byte`, `double`, `float`, `int`, `long`, and `short`.

(resources: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_number.htm)

```
public double dotProduct(AbstractVector<T> vector) {
    double value = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<vector.size(); i++) {
        //you can simply convert the return type to double
        value += this.vector[i].doubleValue() * vector.get(i).doubleValue();
        // if you need the output in different types then  intValue(),longValue(),floatValue() can be used.         
    }
    return value;
}
```

Another way to simply implement multiplication using generics:

```
class Operations<T extends Number> {
    T mul(T t1, T t2) {
        if (t1 instanceof Double) {
            return (T) Double.valueOf((t1.doubleValue() * t2.doubleValue()));
        }
         else if (t1 instanceof Integer) {
            return (T) Integer.valueOf((t1.intValue() * t2.intValue()));
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Operations<Double> o1 = new Operations<Double>();
        System.out.print(o1.mul(2.0, 1.1));
        Operations<Integer> o2 = new Operations<Integer>();
        System.out.print(o2.mul(2, 11));   
    }
}
```